# Unhandled IO error in a bootstrapper WPF(C#) .cs

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio

[New error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OVjR5.png)[image]Okay so I get an error and I don't know how to fix it, any help will be gladly welcome. it's in WPF 2019 visual studio. It's a .cs program [program.cs]

```
   at System.Uri.CreateThis(String uri, Boolean dontEscape, UriKind uriKind)
   at System.Uri..ctor(String uriString)
   at Bootstrapper.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\raduf\Desktop\Exploit Template\Bootstrapper\Program.cs:line 40
```

> System.UriFormatException: 'Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined.' System.UriFormatException HResult=0x80131537 Message=Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined. This exception was originally thrown at this call stack: [External Code] Bootstrapper.Program.Main(string[]) in Program.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace Bootstrapper
{
    class Program
    {
        static String[] files = new string[]
        {
            "https://emaciated-blower.000webhostapp.com/Sploit/MeguSploit/",
        };

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            if (!Directory.Exists(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "/Exploit"))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "/Exploit");
            }
            Console.Title = "MeguSploit Bootstrapper";
            Console.WriteLine("Updating....");

            foreach (Process process in Process.GetProcessesByName("MeguSploit"))
            {
                process.Kill();
            }

            foreach (string file in files)
            {
                string name = file.Substring(file.LastIndexOf("/") + 1);
                try
                {
                    new WebClient().DownloadFile(new Uri(file), Environment.CurrentDirectory + "/Exploit/" + name);
                }
                catch (IOException ex)  //HERE
                {

                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Updated...");
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
            Console.WriteLine("Please go to exploit folder and run the program. Make sure to always ru the bootstrapper to check for updates.");
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to close...");
            Console.ReadKey();
            Environment.Exit(0);
            Console.Read();



        }
    }
}
```

Sorry for my bad code I am new into this world. I am trying to get it working for some hours but I can't.
Thanks, again.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: System.UriFormatException: 'Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined.'
System.UriFormatException
  HResult=0x80131537
  Message=Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined.


  This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
    [External Code]
    Bootstrapper.Program.Main(string[]) in Program.cs

Comment: Have you debugged your code to see the runtime values of `file` and `name`, etc.? To me it doesn't look like your `files` array has URIs to files.

Comment: Yes, here u go : https://ibb.co/WDzWd6H

Comment: Whatever that link is, you can edit your question to add more detail. I'm not going to click some random link.

Comment: It was an image uploading site. Didn't know you can post images, Sorry.

Comment: The value of `file` is "dll" which clearly is not a URI. Trace backwards to find out why.

Comment: Any suggestions? I really don't know how to fix it. Sorry

Comment: I don't know how to fix it either, your `files` array is coming from somewhere not shown in your screenshot. For debugging, hard-code a Known Good Value. That will narrow down where the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your problem is in this line

```
 string name = file.Substring(file.LastIndexOf("/") + 1);
```

According to your definition of the files array, this would give you an empty string for the name.

```
    static String[] files = new string[]
    {
        "https://emaciated-blower.000webhostapp.com/Sploit/MeguSploit/",
    };
```

`file.LastIndexOf("/")` would be grabbing the `/` after MeguSploit.

Also unless you have a need for the Uri, you should just use the `string` overload for the `WebClient().DownloadFile()` method. (Like Below)

```
new WebClient().DownloadFile(file, Environment.CurrentDirectory + "/Exploit/" + name);
```

To download multiple files you would need to define each file that is being downloaded like below.

```
static String[] files = new string[]
{
    "https://emaciated-blower.000webhostapp.com/Sploit/MeguSploit/test.exe",
    "https://emaciated-blower.000webhostapp.com/Sploit/MeguSploit/test.dll",
    // etc...
};
```

Comment: I am so lost, sorry for wasting your time, but I really don't know what to do. I tried your code, replacing the (uri) one and I get System.UriFormatException: 'Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined.'. I am in WPF for about 2 days and wanted to develop an updating feature for a program. Also, I am not speaking a very good english but I get what you are trying to say. I am trying to download .dll and .exe files.

Comment: I've added the new error photo. You can see there better

Comment: Also didn't mean to edit the comment

Comment: It is telling you that it cannot find the path. You need to provide a file name. Try putting something like `new WebClient().DownloadFile(file, Environment.CurrentDirectory + "/Exploit/test.exe");` just for testing purposes.

Comment: Currently your `name` object is empty.

Comment: If I want to download multiple files do I need to change something in the code?

Comment: Updated my answer to include multiple files

Comment: It only downloaded .exe file, other dll didn't download. Also now I can't run .exe file for some reason

Comment: Well you need to define the files that you are wanting to download. It probably downloaded everything it could find at `https://emaciated-blower.000webhostapp.com/Sploit/MeguSploit/` and put it into a single file. Which would not work.

Comment: it is a ftp server type, I just copied the adress to download them, one by one